# How to grab latest image for current residents from MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that holds image information for every resident at my facility.  They have a new image taken each time they arrive and as such have several images associated with their unique id.  I need to be able to retrieve only the most recent image for each resident.

Right now I am seeing an endless and inefficient series of loops to achieve this.

```
$image = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT imagefilename, date_entered, 
         master_name_link FROM Images");
```

Each `master_name_link` can have numerous images associated with it.

I'm sure that I'm just not thinking this through as thoroughly as I could be, but right now I'm stumped.

Comment: ...ORDER BY date_entered LIMIT 1...

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

> $image = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT imagefilename, date_entered, 
>            master_name_link FROM Images ORDER BY date_entered LIMIT 1");